# Writing an instance declaration for Typeable without deriving

Tags: haskell, types, instance

How do I write an actual instance declaration for Typeable? For instance, say I wanted to write an instance for Char where each character had a different type, e.g.

```
instance Typeable Char where
    typeOf 'a' = C
    typeOf 'b' = C -> D
    typeOf 'c' = D -> E
    typeOf     = String
```

Obviously this wouldn't be written like this because the output of typeOf is a TypeRep, but I can't figure out how to actually construct a TypeRep.

Is this even possible? It seems like everything that talks about Typeable assumes that you would use DeriveDataTypeable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well there are a few issues with doing this.

1. It's broken. `typeOf` isn't supposed to be strict in it's argument so `typeOf (undefined :: Char)` should work.
2. It's unsafe. Actually, if you manually create an instance of `Typeable` you won't compile under Safe Haskell.

Keeping this in mind!

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Typeable

data C = C deriving (Typeable)
data D = D deriving (Typeable)
data E = E deriving (Typeable)
newtype Foo = Foo Char

instance Typeable Foo where
  typeOf (Foo 'a') = typeOf (undefined :: C)
  typeOf (Foo 'b') = typeOf (undefined :: C -> D)
  typeOf (Foo 'c') = typeOf (undefined :: D -> E)
  typeOf  _        = typeOf (undefined :: String)
```

Now as an example of why this is terrible, consider

```
what :: Char -> C
what c = if isJust weird then fromJust weird else error "Sanity!"
  where weird = fromDynamic . toDyn $ Foo c
```

Now

```
> what 'a'
  C
> what 'b'
  *** Exception: Sanity!
```

Depending on the representation of how `Foo` this could do all sorts of fun things, like seg fault, spew nonsense answers, or make monkeys fly out of your ears.

[Robert Harper](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/haskell-is-exceptionally-unsafe/) gave a more dramatic example

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

newtype Foo = Foo (() -> IO ())

{- set Foo’s TypeRep to be the same as ErrorCall’s -}
instance Typeable Foo where
  typeOf _ = typeOf (undefined :: ErrorCall)
instance Show Foo where  show _ = ""
instance Exception Foo

main = Control.Exception.catch (error "kaboom") (\ (Foo f) -> f ())
```

Which gives

```
<interactive>: internal error: stg_ap_v_ret
    (GHC version 7.6.3 for x86_64_unknown_linux)
    Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
  C-c C-c
Process haskell aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Awesome, this was what I was looking for. Could you expand on why it's unsafe?

Comment: @thylacine222 I've added an example

Comment: @thylacine222 And a more dramatic one

Comment: @thylacine222: also note that it's very likely future ghc's will only allow `Typeable` instances to be derived, not user-defined.

Comment: @JohnL That's already the case. GHC 7.8 will not allow user-defined Typeable instances.

Comment: @bennofs: I'll believe that when I see a release candidate ;)